Scrolling functionality not working when in react
return (
    <div className='DashboardHome'>
      <Link to="timesheet" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-100} duration={500} ><h5 className='rep'>Reports</h5></Link>
      <Link to="indaccept" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-100} duration={500} ><h5 className='repp'>Task Status</h5></Link>
      <button ref={buttonRef} onClick={updateData} hidden className='reo'>Click Me</button>
      <Completed />
      <Reports />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
Dasboard.css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.DashboardHome{
    background-color: #E2EDE5;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

Reports.js
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from "react-scroll";
import '../style/Reports.css'

function Reports() {
  return (
    <>
      <Link to="headMile1" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-100} duration={500} ><h5 className='timesheet'>Timesheet Report</h5></Link>
    </>
  )
}

export default Reports

Currently, our platform lacks smooth scrolling functionality, which, in my assessment, is pivotal for seamless navigation and overall user satisfaction. In the absence of the DashboardHome div, scrolling operates smoothly, underscoring the potential for enhanced user engagement and ease of access.
